# How to change span text of a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I need to change the text in the span tag next to a list of radiobuttons using Javascript.
I cant change the code that create the the below code. 
Depending on a given condition, I need to modify the text of one of the radio button text.

I can disable a button using the index.

```
document.getElementsByName("estimate[id]")[0].disabled = true;
```

I can change all the span text values

```
var $label = $('input[type=radio]').next();
$label.text('Options');
```

But I cant find out how to change the text on one of the buttons.

```
<form action="/cart/set_estimate" accept-charset="UTF-8"
      id="estimate_shipping_results" autocomplete="off"
      method="post">
  <dl id="estimates">
    <dt><input type="radio" name="estimate[id]" value="170361"
               checked="checked"/>
      <span>Entrega Jueves-Viernes</span></dt>
    <dd>$2.000</dd>
    <dt><input type="radio" name="estimate[id]" value="170483"/>
      <span>Entrega 48h hábiles</span></dt>
    <dd>$3.500</dd>
  </dl>
  div class="estimate_shipping_buttons">
  <input id="set_shipping_button" type="submit" value="Definir Envío"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if I understand your issue right, but to change the text of one span, next to the radio button, you can use:

```
document.getElementsByName("estimate[id]")[0].parentElement.querySelector('span').innerHTML = "text";
```

Comment: THANKS! That is what I needed!